# Having issues in Discord.js with Promise

Tags: node.js, regex, promise, discord.js

i'm trying to make this work, but there's this issue : UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message

```
let regex = /<:\s([a-zA-Z])\w+:\s([0-9])\w+>|<a:\s([a-zA-Z])\w+:\s([0-9])\w+>|<:([a-zA-Z])\w+:([0-9])\w+>|<@!([0-9])\w+>|<@!\s([0-9])\w+>|<@\s([0-9])\w+>|<@([0-9])\w+>|<#([0-9])\w+>/g

async function traduire(msg, lang) {
    translate(msg, {
        to: lang
    }).then(res => {
        str = res.text
        if (!msg.match(regex)) return str.toString()

        MsgJoin = msg.split(" ").join("")
        if (MsgJoin.match(regex)) {
            MsgRegex = MsgJoin.match(regex)
        }

        let RegexStr = str.match(/<(.*?)\>/g)
        let MidMsg = str

        for (let i = 0; i < MsgRegex.length; i++) {
            MidMsg = MidMsg.replace(RegexStr[i], MsgRegex[i])
            FinalMsg = MidMsg
        }

        return FinalMsg.toString()
    })
}

bot.on('message', msg => {
    try {
        let MessTrans = msg.content;
        let reactionFilter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '' && msg.author.id !== "724682218454253588"
        msg.awaitReactions(reactionFilter, {
            max: 1
        }).then(() => {
            const traduction = await traduire(MessTrans, "fr")
            msg.channel.send(traduction)
        })
    } catch (error) {
        msg.channel.send('There\'s an error, try again !')
    }
})
```

the issue is from the msg.channel.send(traduction) but i don't know how to fix it, all I know is that it's a Promise error, and I have to use async / await.

Comment: Your `traduire` function does not `return` anything. Either drop the `async`, and `return` the promise chain; or remove the `.then()` syntax and replace it with an `await`.

Comment: Also `str` appears to be an undeclared variable. Make sure to always use strict mode.

Comment: How can I return the promise chain ?

Comment: You return it by `return`ing the promise returned by the `.then()` call

Comment: Yeah, but what after the "return" ?

Comment: You could just return the chain as is, or await the promise to resolve.